Unexpected Behavior in Transistor-Coupled Astable Multivibrator Output
I tried to build an astable multivibrator to periodically run a vibration motor. I coupled the motor to the oscillator via a BJT. The circuit is:

The expected collector voltage of Q3 is:

To test the oscillator, I connected it first to an LED light and a 200 Ohm resistor (so instead of R_L in the circuit above). The circuit worked as expected, and the LED lit up. For comparison, I measured the output with the oscilloscope (below the LED, above the collector). As expected, we see several transitions between the ON to the OFF states:

When I try to connect my vibration motor (something similar to this motor, but with 5V input voltage), the circuit fails, and the motor doesn't stay in the ON state for the designed time period. It starts to vibrate for a very short period and then shuts down. The output on the oscilloscope shows that as soon as the motor starts to run, it returns to the OFF state:

When I connected the motor directly to a 5V supply, it runs without a problem. When I ran the following circuit, the motor also ran without a problem:

I measured the motor's ohmic resistance with a voltmeter, and it is 33 Ohms. It's current consumption is 70mA for 3V and 120mA for 5V. If you can advise me as to why the circuit failed, I would be grateful.
Best
Edit:
I want to clarify that I used those component values only for testing purposes, to reduce the time constants so that I wouldn't have to wait a long time to see if there were any problems. In my actual circuit, I plan to use the following component values: R1 = R4 = 36kΩ; R2 = 180kΩ; R3 = 6MΩ; C3 = 100µF; C2 = 220µF. This would give me a T_off of about 10 minutes and a T_on of about 5 seconds. I will use 2 coin batteries to provide a 6V supply. I don't need high accuracy in my circuit, and a deviation of even 2 minutes would be completely acceptable. What is important to me is low energy consumption and a small volumetric size for the circuit, as I will be connecting it to a strap and carrying it on me. All other aspects are not important.

In LTspice if you want diagonal wires hold CTRL when drawing.

@GodJihyo Thanks! I didn't know that, my sketches will be prettier now :)

@Arad What is the motor current when the motor shaft  is (a) unloaded, &  (b) loaded?

@FabioBarone 70µA for 3V, 120µA for 5V. I tried to load the motor by holding it firmly with my fingers, but it didn't change the current consumption. Unfortunatly I can't tell you how it will perform with my actual load because I haven't built the system yet.

@Arad  Is that 70 Micro-amps or 70 milli-amps?  This data also belongs in the main question.

@FabioBarone uff I am sorry, I wrote µA in the other thread and messed up the units here. I mean mA... 70mA for 3V, 120mA for 5V. I add it to my main question.

You are probably not switching enough current for the motor to work. Note that in your second schematic there’s no base resistor, while in your first circuit it’s 10k. The collector current will be limited by that.
You can try a stronger buffer, maybe a darlington.

Thanks! It worked in a darlington configuration.

Not surprising the bottom circuit works in simulation, but you will blow the transistor in a real circuit since there is nothing to limit the base current.
You likely need more base drive for Q3, but that could interfere with the multivibrator operation, so try two transistors in a Darlington configuration for Q3.

Thanks! It worked in a darlington configuration.

Put a resistor in series with the base pin of Q3. This resistor value must be at least 5 times that of R4.  Without this resistor, the voltage at Q2 collect pin is restricted, which will affect the operation of your astable multivibrator.
Depending on the load R_L, this change may cause the Q3 to not be fully turned on when required.  If that is the case, then convert Q3 to a Darlington.

Thanks! I tried this configuration just now. At first, I tried a 50k resistor, but unfortunately, the base current was too low, and the motor didn't turn on. IThe motor ran on low power when I used a 10k resistor. However, I just used this circuit for testing; in my actual circuit, I will have a lower time constant, so I will need to use larger resistors. Therefore, I will have to use the Darlington configuration.

I just looked at the motor you are using.  Data states it draws 80mA idle, meaning it draws more than that when mechanically loaded.  You should connect this motor to a power supply and measure how much current it draws when loaded in your application.  That is an important data point to have when designing these circuits.

Motor data: 3V, 80mA at idle.  Current when loaded is not known.  Equivalent resistance at idle is 3V /80mA = 37.5 ohm.   Be careful when applying more than 3V to this motor, you may be exceeding its electrical ratings

@Arad  Sorry, I had forgotten to direct comments to you.

Sorry, I missed your comment earlier. The motor I have looks just like the one I posted here, but apparently the specifications are different. My motor can take 5V, which I didn’t notice when I first posted about it. I'm editing my main post to clarify that :)

The base of Q3 cannot rise above +0.7V, due to its base-emitter junction. That junction behaves like a diode. To allow Q3's base to rise above 0.7V, which would be required if you wish the circuit to have as if Q3 weren't there, you must insert a resistance between its base and Q2's collector.
Q3's collector current is motor current \$I_C\$:
$$ I_C = \frac{5V}{33\Omega} = 150mA $$
The required Q3 base current would be \$\beta=250\$ times lower, but to guarantee saturation (even if you were to use a much lower gain device), I would suggest a factor of 50 difference:
$$ I_B = \frac{I_C}{50} = 3mA $$
To obtain 3mA into the base of Q3 would require a resistance of \$R_B\$ between the base and the positive supply:
$$ R_B = \frac{5V}{3mA} = 1.7k\Omega $$
Base current would have to flow from the positive supply, down through R4, and then through RB, meaning that the combined resistance (in series) of both of those resistances should not exceed 1.7kΩ. They still form a potential divider, preventing Q2's collector from rising all the way to +5V, so to mitigate that you would make R4 small compared to RB, say \$R_4 = 220\Omega\$ and \$R_B=1.5k\$:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This will of course require changes to other timing elements to obtain the same frequency of oscillation.
Since Q2 is able to sink a lot more current to ground than R4 can source from +5V, it makes sense to take advantage of this. Try changing Q3 to a PNP type:

simulate this circuit
This permits Q2's collector to adopt any potential, and because Q2 now sinks all the required base current for Q3, the frequency of oscillation will not be very different from an oscillator unloaded by Q3.
While those ideas solve your problem (of how to operate Q3), typically the "load" is placed at the collector of either Q1 or Q2, and I see no reason why you wouldn't do that:

simulate this circuit

Thanks! Your comment really helped my understanding of electronics. I can't place the motor in series with R4, however, because I plan to make this oscillator have a much longer period (10 minutes OFF, 10 seconds ON). The resistors are really large, and I get no current in the branch with R4. I used this circuit only for testing so that I wouldn't have to wait 10 minutes to see if there's a problem.

@Arad Motor not in series with R4, replacing R4 altogether. Try it, timing is mostly determined by R3 and R2, not so much by R4 or R1.

I tried to simulate it, and unfortunately, it doesn't work. In my actual circuit, I have R2 = 160k and R3 = 6Meg. If R1 and R4 are lower than around 5k, the circuit doesn't work properly (in the simualtion).

@Arad The transistors have limited current gain, and Q2 base current must be large enough to obtain the required motor current. Consequently all resistors sourcing that base current must be sufficiently small. With collector resistance R4=33Ω (the motor), I would try for R1=150Ω and R2=R3=1.5kΩ. Of course the timing capacitors will have to be commensurately larger, to obtain the same frequency of oscillation. If that's a problem, then you'll have to use the additional transistor Q3, as in my first two schematics.

@Arad this design is notoriously difficult to get right, with predictable and consistent behaviour, which is why things like the 555 timer IC (and many other solutions) exist. If you insist on using this two-transistor design, then you must also be prepared to calculate the currents everywhere, to obtain appropriate resistance values.

I thought about the 555, but its problem is that T_ON ≥ T_OFF. I need the motor to pulse around every 10 min (accuracy isn't important), so T_OFF = 10 min and T_ON = 5 s, which I can't realize with the 555. I sized the components through simulation by trial and error until I got the right characteristics. I have R1 = R4 = 36k, R2 = 160k, R3 = 6Meg, C3 = 100u, C2 = 220u. I built the circuit with the Darlington configuration and measured a vibration pulse around every 10 minutes, so the design worked. I can't use smaller resistor values because the capacitors would be way too large.

@Arad Use two 555 timers.  One to set the long time OFF pulse (10 mins), the other to set the short ON pulse (5 seconds).

@FabioBarone Another advantage of my circuit is that it consumes much less power than the 555 timer. My circuit, with the large resistors, consumes around 290µW in idle state, which is significantly lower than the 22.5mW consumed by one 555 timer. What would be the advantages of using a 555 timer if my astable multivibrator is already functioning well?

@Arad Your original post did not mention low power as a requirement, & the schematic does not show the large resistor values you mentioned.

@Arad The CMOS version of the 555 timer consumes less than 1mW at 5V at idle, refer datasheet for LMC555.

@Arad You may learn more low-power techniques from this post: ||  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/216379/341959

@FabioBarone I didn't mention the high resistors in my main post because it goes beyond the scope of the discussion. My actual circuit uses a large time constant, but for testing I used a low time constant so that I wouldn't have to wait 10 minutes each time to see if it works. Since the problem was similar in both circuits, I posted the issue with the lower component values. The values in my actual circuit are posted here above in this thread.

@FabioBarone I plan to run my circuit on batteries, so it needs to be low power. Even if I use a CMOS 555 timer with 1mW consumption, it consumes 3 times more power than my circuit, and 6 times more if I use two 555s. So, I return to my question: why should I run my circuit with two 555s if it works just fine as it is?

@Arad A 1mW CMOS 555 at 5V requires 200μA. Your circuit here draws more than twice that amount. The 555 timer will have way more accurate timing than yours. The 555 will drive a single transistor perfectly, for the full 5V across the motor, whereas the darlington solution loses 0.7V. You say $T_{ON}>T_{OFF}$, which is true, but you can use a PNP instead of NPN to reverse that. You say this works fine, I very much doubt it, at 10min. intervals. The CMOS 555 is superior in pretty much every respect.

@Arad  The values in my actual circuit are posted here above in this thread  || This info should be in the original question, edit the OP to add an update.  Also add any power budget requirements.

@SimonFitch, Regarding the current, you are right; I accidentally mistook my current consumption of 290µA for the power consumption. I don't need high accuracy in my circuit; even a 2-minute standard deviation would be completely acceptable. However, after reading your messages, I actually believe that the 555 circuit would be a better option and provide me with a small challenge, so I will try to build it. My main considerations are power consumption and size, and I think I can indeed make the circuit smaller with the 555. I'll at least try that. Thank you for your help and your time! :)

@FabioBarone Done.

Hey Simon and Fabio (I can't tag two people), I just wanted to let you know that I tried making the circuit with a 555 timer and a PNP transistor, and I think it will be better for my application. I'm starting to work on the new design now. Thank you for your help! It really means a lot to me.

@Arad you're welcome

@Arad Glad to hear it.  It would be interesting to hear your results, please post an update of your new circuit & test results, I'd like to see its power draw.  Cheers.

@FabioBarone I will update it :)
